# How to point to a deep nested element in hash?

Tags: ruby

In the following,

```
a={a:{b:{c:[]}}}
d=a[:a][:b][:c]
d=[1]
```

how I can make `d` point to `a[:a][:b][:c]` so that when I change `d`, `a[:a][:b][:c]` is also changed?

```
a[:a][:b][:c] # => []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers here are good, but let's take a look at your code here:

```
d=a[:a][:b][:c]
puts d #[]
d=[1]
puts d #[1]
```

Remember when you assign `d=[1]` everything you did before in terms of assignment is lost. When things seem strange, thing about how you've assigned a variable and if you've accidentally reassigned it like you did.

You can therefore see, that a proper assignment such as:

```
d[0]=1
```

will do what you want, since the `[0]` index is what you assigned earlier that you want to change.

Hope this helps - if you need further clarification, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 3):

You should change the array object, but not just assign a new array to the variable.

Use

```
d << 1
```

or

```
d.push 1
```

or

```
d[0] = 1
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Assign to `a[:a][:b][:c]`, not to `d`.

```
a[:a][:b][:c] = [1]
```